# Get EkEvent's Calendar Color Reference

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ekevent

So currently, I have this `EkEvent`:

```
EKEvent <0xb12dc30> {EKEvent <0xb12dc30> {title = Mitchell Smith’s Birthday; location = (null); calendar = EKCalendar <0x9a532c0> {title = Birthdays; type = Birthday; allowsModify = NO; color = #8295AF;}; alarms = (null); URL = (null); lastModified = (null); timeZone = (null)}; location = (null); startDate = 2013-08-13 07:00:00 +0000; endDate = 2013-08-14 06:59:59 +0000; allDay = 1; floating = 1; recurrence = EKRecurrenceRule <0xb2199e0> RRULE FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1; attendees = (null)}
```

I successfully parse to the `EKCalendar` Key doing this :

```
NSLog(@"%@", [event valueForKey:@"calendar"]);
```

Which prints :
`EKCalendar <0x9a532c0> {title = Birthdays; type = Birthday; allowsModify = NO; color = #8295AF;}`

Then I attempt to get the `EKCalendar`'s Color attribute doing this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[event valueForKey:@"calendar"] valueForKeyPath:@"color"]);
```

Which prints:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<EKCalendar 0x9a532c0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key color.'
```

I am able to get the other attributes of `EKCalendar`, but when I access the `color` attribute, i get a crash EVERY time :(. So `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key color` is what I need to understand, anyone have any ideas on how to get this value?

My main goal is to get the color attribute, convert the "hex" number to an `RBG` color then use quartz to display a small dot of the color. I am using this for a calendar application I am currently implementing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a CGColor public property available on EKCalendar. You should be using this. Apple could change how their description method prints out at ant time, breaking your code.

```
 UIColor *calendarColor = [UIColor colorWithCGColor:calendar.CGColor];
```

Comment: I made an edit to the question, think you could help out ? :)

Comment: you saved me... it is working and I have added the swift code in my answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

According to the doc of [EKCalendar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Reference/EKCalendarClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) there is no `color` property that you can access but there is a `CGColor` property you can access.

```
@property(nonatomic) CGColorRef CGColor
```

Comment: I made an edit to the question, think you could help out ? :)

Answer (score 2):

Swift version of **atomkirk** answer. I just used in May 2018 and It is working.

From Event ref:

```
let eventCalendarColor = UIColor.init(cgColor: event.calendar.cgColor)
```

From Calendar ref:

```
let calendarColor = UIColor.init(cgColor: calendar.cgColor)
```